# Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've an existing project (EP) written in Objective C. Our team has decided to develop a new project (NP) in Swift and add the existing project (written in Objective C) as a feature in the new project (show existing app in one tab as a feature).

Here is what I did:

1. Created a new project in Swift and added the existing project as a sub project in Xcode
2. Under Build phases of new project, I added existing project(build product) as Target Dependencies.
3. Created a Bridging Header for Swift Project (new project-Bridging-Header.h) and referred the header in **Objective-C Bridging header** as **NP/NP-Bridging-Header.h** under **Build Settings** of new project.
4. Under header search path, I added **$(SRCROOT)/Path_To_Sub_Project** and set it as recursive. (both in project and target of new project)
5. Under **Other Linker Flags**, added **-all_load** and **-ObjC**.
6. Added required Objective-C files in bridging header file.

Issue:
   In a new project, when I try to refer objective c class, I am getting reference issue.

```
ViewController.swift
  //viewdidload
   let vc = HomeViewController() //This is an objective c class.
```

HomeViewController is recognised by Xcode as it is autofilled while typing and Xcode didn't throw any live issues. But when I try to build the new project, I am getting the following error.

Error:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_HomeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is to do with the architecture your are compiling for.

Comment: i tried with complete new objc and swift project. but i am getting the same error

Comment: Under the Project Settings there is a setting Valid Architectures. You must have selected "x86_64" and the objc does not have that version compiled. If you remove that setting and stick with arm64, armv7 armv7s then I think it will work. (I'm just guessing). It might be that you are building for an early iOS version like 7 or 8 that is not supported by the objC Library.